# Celery with non-homogenous tasks

Tags: python, task, celery, celery-task

I have two celery workers, worker 1 has tasks A and B, worker 2 with tasks A, B, and C. If I submit a task C, it doesn't seem to be executed in the celery worker that has task C; is there some way I can make sure that only worker 2 gets assigned tasks C?

Comment: What's the point of having a distributed job queue if you don't want some jobs be be executed on some servers?

Comment: That's not really germane to the question. Assume for the sake of argument that I have a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd take a look at [routing tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) in the documentation. You can create queues with specific topics, and specify which worker(s) can handle which queue(s).